# Historic Boston Sites - Good Resource

Tags: online-resources, sightseeing, guides, boston

I plan to visit Boston this year; I'm looking to hit up the historical sites, and trying to find a good guide of all of the sites.  Is there one out there online, or a good one I can find or buy when I'm in the city, not including all of the tours they offer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good starting point is the [Freedom Trail](https://www.thefreedomtrail.org/) -- it's a nice primer on Boston history. They also offer walking tours. The trail includes:

- Boston Common
- Massachusetts State House
- Park Street Church
- Granary Burying Ground
- King’s Chapel
- King’s Chapel Burying Ground
- Benjamin Franklin Statue & Boston Latin School
- Old Corner Book Store
- Old South Meeting House
- Old State House
- Site of Boston Massacre
- Faneuil Hall
- Paul Revere House
- Old North Church
- Copp’s Hill Burying Ground
- Bunker Hill Monument
- USS Constitution

Beyond that, depending on your interests there are numerous other options. You could visit the Harvard University campus in Cambridge (an easy ride on [the T red line](https://www.mbta.com/)), Fenway Park, Newbury Street (some typical Boston architecture, plus a decent choice of shopping & restaurants), etc.

The [Celebrate Boston](http://www.celebrateboston.com/) site is a good resource for what's happening in Boston and what's worth seeing. I know that you mentioned historic, but worth mentioning [Arts Boston](https://www.artsboston.org/) for additional arts-related listings.

Also, have a look at [MassHome's Boston Page](http://www.masshome.com/boston.html). Not very pretty, but has lots of links to different tourist sites in Boston.